# The spring boot edit starters context menu option does not show up under rightclicking pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

The spring boot edit starters context menu for downloading content to pom.xml automatically is not visible in my eclipse, although Spring Tool Suite is properly installed. Also. the Boot Dashboard for Development Tools will not show up.

> Error:  java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plugin
>   "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash".

What could this be, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a hard-to-debug issue and probably caused by some incompatibilities among installed plugins. You can try to start up Eclipse/STS with the `-clean` option, this causes the runtime to re-evaluate bundle resolution (among other things), and in some rare cases that helps. But it doesn't help if there is a real underlying incompatibility. And that is hard to identify from the outside, we would need a lot more details to debug this.

I would recommend to download a ready-to-use STS distribution and go from there. It contains a full Eclipse JEE package plus the Spring IDE plugins pre-installed. I know that starting from a fresh install might cause additional work if you need additional third-party plugins being installed again, but it would at least give you a good starting point. And if the problem arises again after installing certain plugins, we would at least have a potentially reproducible path towards the issue that we could use to track down the issue on our end.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow these steps -

1. Right click "pom.xml"
2. Select "Spring" item
3. Click "Add Starters"

For your reference,
[image]